# Expectation-Maximization algorithm for missing data in R (with GLMM)

Tags: r, missing-data, expectation-maximization

Here is a simplified dataset for my real data: for a

```
df=(value=c(1, 2, 3, NA), V1=c(3,5,1,6), V2=c("apple", "apple", "pear", "pear"), V3=c("a", "b", "c", "b"), V4=c(2011, 2012, 2013, 2013))
```

How to use Expectation maximization algorithm to impute for the missing value in r?

I previously had this in mind: When ignore then missing value, I fit the data into a GLMM model in which V1 and V2 were fixed variables and V3 and V4 were random variables.

Please help me with R script! Thank you very much.